# Kill Service After BootUp Start android

Tags: android, service

Hello
How can i kill my service when my Mobile Boot ups.

For example i want to achieve that my service starts on Boot up and after doing all its Task it should be Exit/Killed/Removed.

PLease guide.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stopSelf();   
stopForground(true);
```

both works for me!

Thanks to capDroid!